# Move files containing Brackets and Year eg (1999)

Tags: find, move

I want to selectivly move all files that are movies with the year at the end of the filename. I have a program that renames movies and fixes the format which always uses `Moviename (YEAR).extension` format.

I tried `mv *(*).*` but it just moved everything. I figure the best way would be to do something like move files with brackets and 4 characters in brackets. Also/Or the brackets will always come before the `.extension`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*'('*')'.*` should work. 
Better yet, `*'('????')'.*` should get only the names
that have four characters between the parentheses. 
Parentheses are special characters, so you have to put them in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 find . -type f -iname "*(*).*" -exec mv  -t ../Final/ {} +
```

Comment: That would move the file `hello (world). hiya` too.

Comment: Thankfully none of my movies arw formatted in such a way. Which I know 100%